# Can one use the Big-O notation to find an aympototic expansion of $a_n=a_{n-1}+1/a_{n-1}$

Tags: calculus

Can one use the Big-O notation to find an aympototic expansion of 
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+1/a_{n-1}$$
Here $a_1=1$,Thank you very much
Well, I guess it is $$\sqrt{2n}(1+O(1/n))$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the big-$O$ notation is never required to be a strict bound, and it's only an upper bound. So $n=O(n^2)$. So "using big-$O$ notation" is very vague.

That being said, let's see if we can't find a big-$\Theta$ (two-sided bound of the same flavor as big-$O$) for your sequence. If we set
$$
b_{n+1}=b_n+\left\lfloor\frac1{b_n}\right\rfloor, \quad b_1=1
$$
then clearly $b_n\geq a_n$. And the function $n\mapsto b_{n+1}-1$ is a linear interpolation of the inverse of the triangular numbers, meaning that for a triangular number $T(k)$, we have $b_{T(k)+1}-1=k$, and for intervals between consecutive triangular numbers, $b_n$ is a linear function.

This implies $n-1\geq\frac{b_{n}(b_{n}-1)}2$. Solving this inequality for $b_n$, we get $$b_n\leq\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}2\\<\frac{1+\sqrt{9n}}2<2\sqrt n$$ So $b_n$, and therefore $a_n$, is bounded above by $2\sqrt n$. (Of course, your upper bound of $\sqrt{2n}(1+O(1/n))$ is (asymptotically) stricter. I would love to see a proof of that.)

Working further on this upper bound, we get
$$
a_n\leq 2\sqrt n\\
\frac1{a_n}\geq \frac1{2\sqrt1}\\
\frac1{a_n}>\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\\
\frac1{a_n}>\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)}\\
\frac1{a_n}>\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n
$$
Now set $c_n=\sqrt n$. Then
$$
c_{n+1}=c_n+(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n),\quad c_1=1
$$
Comparing that to
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac1{a_n}, \quad a_1=1
$$
we see that we have $a_n\geq\sqrt n$.

Thus $\sqrt n\leq a_n\leq 2\sqrt n$, meaning
$$
a_n=\Theta(\sqrt n)
$$